# What does Cristiano Ronaldo mean when used as an adjective?

Tags: meaning, usage, slang

The context is "[something] is so **Cristiano Ronaldo**". I saw this more than 3 times in different places not related to sports.

I know he is a great, famous football player, but I don't know what word can be used to sum up his image in the public mind.

So, does this mean [something] is so **brilliant** or so **cool**? Or just because the speaker is the fans of Ronaldo?

**Update**

I'm not an English speaker, so I do not know if there is any novel rhetoric for specific groups and countries about this usage. For example "raining cats and dogs" is meaningless and sounds crazy in my native language. Isn't it a question of slang usage? I don't understand why a Nazi word is used for analogy.

Comment: Probably something characteristic or typical of Ronaldo. "Invading a country and killing millions of people? That's so Adolf Hitler!" You saw it three times but did not say where or quote the text seen.

Comment: @Michael Harvey Clearly these scenarios have nothing in common. What do you think when a code developer say "My code is so Adolf Hitler"? Are you using this horrible example on purpose?

Comment: A code developer would use an example relevant to coding.

Comment: That search engine code is so Larry Page! That weird indented language is so Guido van Rossum!

Comment: That tax evasion is so Christian Ronaldo! Or it might be his haircut.

Comment: @Michael Harvey So what is the potential connections between a piece of code and football player?I can not understand.  I use this example because a programmer really said that.

Comment: I know nothing about soccer, but if Christian Ronaldo is considered by soccer fans to be an especially skilled, stylish, talented (etc) football player, then probably the coder thinks he or she is an especially skilled, stylish, talented (etc) programmer.

Comment: @Krahmal If you look at my answer, you will see that it is not a precise locution. It sounds to me as if the programmer thought the code exhibited some attribute that is similar to an attribute of a football player. So if the programmer thinks that the football player plays elegantly and that the code is also elegant, he might use that locution. It is fashionable but vague.

Comment: Talented or elegant. Good reason. And @Stuart F said haircut, unique appearance is also a possible direction. So we seem to be able to conclude that in this case, at least it is biased towards the positive, isn' t it?

Comment: @Krahmal - it's 'positive' if you like soccer players and boastful coders. I like neither.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about "English". It's about some characteristic stereotypically associated with a particular ***footballer*** (who isn't even English himself; he's Portuguese). I know English pretty well myself, but I've no idea what specific thing about Ronaldo is being referenced in the cited usage.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Closing this would be so Fumble Fingers/

Comment: I'd say the construction itself is just "short for" an underlying "original" along the lines of *That's so **typical of** [whoever typically does or reminds one of whatever "that" is]*.

Comment: What Nazi word? I don't see anything of the kind in any if the posts. Can you please clarify IN the question or simply remove the reference.

Comment: If you must refer to.something said in a comment, then make that clear and make sure to mention the commenter's username. Adolf Hitler is a *name*, despicable though he was, the name of the Nazi leader is not a Nazi word.

Comment: I upvoted the comment by Michael Harvey's comment because it says **You saw it three times but did not say where or quote the text seen.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usage that you are referring to is a fad of the chattering professions like sports commentators.

> That is so {person’s name}

means, if the topic is the named person,

> That is so typical of {person’s name}

or means, if the topic is not the named person,

> That is so similar to {person’s name}

It is a currently trendy form of ellipsis.

Comment: That answer is so Jeff Morrow!

Comment: I like "it is a fad of the chattering professions". In many languages people say "That is so {person’s name}", but I guess Ronaldo may has some special meaning because only this name appears suddenly seemingly unrelated to the subject

Comment: @Krahmal I think the use of Ronaldo's name as a noun-adjective meaning "excellent, accomplished, expert, etc" being a recent thing is because he is famous right now. They didn't say it two years ago, and I expect they won't be saying in in two years from now.

Answer (score 0):

It means that some football play (soccer) is like the style of playing of Cristiano Ronaldo.

Given his career, it can be several ideas. They are all here.

[The Tactical Evolution of Cristiano Ronaldo](https://breakingthelines.com/player-stories/the-tactical-evolution-of-cristiano-ronaldo/)

OR Like Cristiano Ronaldo

The idiomatic usage in English of "That is so [name of celebrity}" to describe something someone does is very common.

Comment: The OP says that the quotations were not related to sports!

Comment: Perhaps but then we need more context otherwise it is undoable. In any event, it just means like Cristiano Ronaldo.